# html5 trying to add a password requirements title

Tags: html, forms, validation

I want to have a requirement title under the second password box but 'title' doesn't seem to be working for me..

```
<form action="register.php" method="post">
    <p>
        First Name: 
        <input type="text" name="first_name" size="15" maxlength="20" required pattern="[a-zA-Z]+" required oninvalid="this.setCustomValidity(this.willValidate?'':'Please enter first name')"></input>
    </p>
    <p>
        Last Name: 
        <input type="text" name="last_name" size="15" maxlength="40" required pattern="[a-zA-Z]+" oninvalid="this.setCustomValidity(this.willValidate?'':'Please enter last name')"></input>>
    </p>
    <p>
        Email Address: 
        <input type="email" name="email" size="20" maxlength="60" required oninvalid="this.setCustomValidity(this.willValidate?'':'Please enter a vaild email')"></input>
    </p>
    <p>
        Password: 
        <input type="password" required pattern="(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z]).{8,}" name="pass1" onchange="form.pass2.pattern = this.value;" size="10" maxlength="20" required oninvalid="this.setCustomValidity('Please Enter a valid password')"></input>
    </p>
    <p>
        Confirm Password: 
        <input type="password" required pattern="(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z]).{8,}" name="pass2" size="10" maxlength="20" title="Must contain at least one number and one uppercase and lowercase letter, and at least 8 or more characters">
    </p>
    <p>
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Register" />
    </p>
</form>
```

Comment: hmm, that edit still didn't add that text to page..

Comment: Your markup is invalid, `<input>` is self-closing, and doesn't require a closing tag. Remove `</input>`

Answer (score 0):

I guess I was overthinking this. I just added this in the form and it displayed the text.

Password must contain at least one number and one uppercase and lowercase letter, and at least 8 or more characters

Comment: I think what you should be using is `<label>` for the form fields, to provide text about that particular field. Also, before others start moaning, you shouldn't have added this as an answer, but edited your question to include it as more information.